# How to Implement Back-Face Culling in a 3D Javascript Engine

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d

Recently I've been working on creating a 3D graphics engine in Javascript. Currently, the camera can move in the x, y, and z axis (working on learning how to rotate the camera) and shapes can be rotated. Shapes are generated based on groups of vertices that make up a face.

An example of the drawing code for the shapes is as below:

```
function renderShapes() {
for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { // For each object
    for (j = 0; j < objects[i].faces.length; j++) { // For each face
        var face = objects[i].faces[j];

        var P = project(face[0],objects[i].type);
        if (P == false) { // project the coordinates based on camera. 
            continue;
        }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(P.x + cx, - P.y + cy); // Start line at first vertex

        // Draw the other vertices that make up the face
        for (l = 0; l < face.length; l++) {
            P = project(face[l],objects[i].type);
            if (P == false) {
                continue;
            }
            ctx.lineTo(P.x + cx, -P.y + cy); // Draw line to the next vertex
        }


        // Close the path and draw the face
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        if (objects[i].color != undefined) { // Fill in a color if the object has color property
            ctx.fillStyle = objects[i].color;
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This above code, generates something roughly like this depending on how I rotate it:

[image: Example]

Everything works perfectly, except that all faces are drawn, and based on their order in the object array, may overlap one or the other. The red cube is an example of my problem. The blue diamond is an example of what I want to achieve, clean faces that are only rendered based on what the camera can see. Instead of rendering all 8 faces of the diamond, it should only render the 4 visible ones. Instead of rendering all 6 faces of the cube, it should only render the 2 visible ones.

I have researched into it to find back-face culling, although the examples were either non-existent, in the wrong language, or simply hard to understand or fit into my case.

Can anyone explain to me, in layman's terms how back-face culling works? And if possible, a Javascript example of it that could be implemented into my code?

Alternatively, is there a different word or phrase for what I'm trying to achieve or a different process or algorithm that would be better suited?

Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between backface culling (prevent faces whose normal points away from the camera from being drawn) and z-ordering. Software renderers may use binary space partitioning trees for the later. If you are only rendering a single convex object however, backface culling has the same effect. If your scene is more complex, you need either a z-buffer (depth buffer) which is slow without hardware support or - as already said - a binary space partitioning tree.

Comment: Ahhhh okay, thank you. I'll look into that